# Tagging system and score system

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, database-schema, tagging

I want to track keywords and have a score system in my database for each user.

I'll have a `user` table and their `website` table.

user table will have basics of user id, email, password, etc
website table will have id, user_id, keywords, and score.

So I will keep all their keywords (max 5 keywords) in a website table implementing the MySQLicious tagging solution.

The question I have is, I will be constantly updating the score so should I also keep the "score" field in website table or create a brand new table and link all the scores based on website's id field??

edit: also should I keep the keywords in the same table or separate them?

Comment: The score is relevant to what, the user or their websites?

Comment: Why not have another table for the keywords:  `keyword{id, website_id, keyword}`?  Then you don't have to limit the keywords to any amount.  Also, please don't store the actual password in the user table.  As for the score, what benefit do you see keeping the score in a separate table?

Comment: @MPelletier: relevant To their webiste

Comment: @Marvo: (the password will be encrypted of course)
DB design: It's a mysqlicious solution (I don't care about limiting them to 255 characters) vs what you are proposing is Scuttle solution. Both have benefits and disavantages http://tagging.pui.ch/post/37027745720/tags-database-schemas

I am just wondering if I should keep the score in the same table or separate it into it's own score{id, website_id, score} table.

Comment: If the relationship for website to score is "1,1", there is no point in making it two tables.

Comment: @CodeCrack FYI, the password should not be stored in the database at all, encrypted or not. You should only store the [salted password hash](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12538258/533120), and if you are really paranoid, [put the security into a separate tier](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13326205/533120).

Comment: Should I keep the keywords in the same table or separate them?

Comment: I'm personally going to implement my own in a separate, normalized table.  I figure I can use a view (normalized or otherwise) later to improve performance if it comes to that.  But your link about the different strategies to tags is certainly food for thought.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you have is a score, it is best to add it to the website table. In most cases, making a separate table  complicates things while offering little advantage. However, there are some cases in which you may want to make a separate table:

- You have many many websites and only some of them have a score. Instead of storing NULL scores for most websites, you add a separate table that only stores scores for websites that have them.
- The website and scores do not have a one-on-one relation, or that relation has properties on  its own (not likely in your scenario).
- You have a lot of websites already and are now adding the score functionality. You maybe don't want to change the database schema because that takes a long time when deploying the new version of your app. Instead of changing the website table, which may take a long time, you add a new table.

Comment: Ok that makes sense but won't the database get slow since we are also running LIKE '%on%' commands on it for tagging and updating/changing the score as well.?

Comment: What if I have 1 million users and sites. The table will be hit everytime to update a website score and everytime there is a search. How do you scale that?

Comment: First, use row-level locking and not table-level locking. Second, if you look up a website or score by a primary key this is very fast, no matter how many rows are in your table. If you look up a website by some other column, add an index to it.

Answer (score 0):

Just keep score in the same table. There is no benefit if you keep it in a separate table. If you want to update you can directly update the table with the new score there is no other benefit if you separate those table, except some burden of foreign keys.

Comment: What if I have 1 million users and sites. The table will be hit everytime to update a website score and everytime there is a search. How do you scale that?