# password and mobile types in database

Tags: database, database-design

I have "Customer" table:

```
CREATE TABLE Customer
(
    ID INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    Username CHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    Password CHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    LastName CHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    PhoneNumber BIGINT NOT NULL,
    MobileNumber BIGINT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (ID)
) 
;
```

I used `char` for password type, is this right? And for mobile number I used `bigint`, is this right? If not what should I do ? And what is the SQL statement for it? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As these fields will all be variable lengths you should definitely use VARCHAR instead of CHAR for 'Username', 'Password' & 'Lastname'. If you have limits on the lengths these then you can always limit the VARCHAR type to that limit.

As for 'PhoneNumber' & 'MobileNumber', you won't be performing any calculations with these values, so there's no reason not to store them as VARCHAR, not to mention that telephone number often contain a 0 as the first character which cannot be stored as an INT of any kind.

Something like:

```
CREATE TABLE `Customer` (
 `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `Username` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
 `Password` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
 `LastName` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
 `PhoneNumber` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
 `MobileNumber` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Answer (score 0):

All these questions matter on the requirements that you have...for example
You can use `BIGINT` for the `MobileNumber` if there are only going to be numbers in this field. 
You will use `VARCHAR` if there can also be characters in it.
Both `VARCHAR` and `CHAR` have their own advantages and disadvantages.
Using `VARCHAR` gives you the freedom to have as many characters as you like in a single string, 
For example `VARCHAR(30)` can store upto 30 characters, and if there are less characters in it, then the rest memory is dumped automatically. You can also use `VARCHAR(max)` for this purpose, it will use all the characters passed and then dump the rest of the memory
`CHAR(30)` will also store 30 characters but it will not take care of the memory.
Memory may not be the issue in a smaller programs, but it can make significant effect if the program is huge.

Comment: i got u for mobile number, but for password , what should i put? i need to make hash for password then storing the hash of it in that field

Comment: again it depends on which algorithm you are using it to for the encryption, in my application i have used the `VARCHAR(256)` for the hash.

Comment: and if it answers your question, then please mark it answered..:D

Answer (score 0):

For the password, use an array of bytes<sup>1</sup> and store a one-way **hash** of the password. When the time comes to verify the password user has entered, hash it and compare it with the stored hash.

On top of that you should also use [salting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_%28cryptography%29) and (ideally) separate the whole authentication infrastructure to its own server beyond a firewall and a well-defined API.

Related answers:

- [How necessary is it to Encrypt database password field](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12538258/533120)
- [store users and pass in single table or seperate table](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13326205/533120)

---

<sup>1</sup> `RAW` in Oracle, `bytea` in PostgreSQL, `varbinary` in MS SQL Server, `BLOB` in MySQL etc...