# How to secure username, password, api_keys

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, security, database-design, passwords

We are building a rails application backed by mysql which will store sensitive information such as username, password, api_key which are specific to each logged in user.

Is there a gem which will allow protection of such production data against stealing by internal team members or external folks.

We don't want sensitive information to be printed in logs
We should be able to prevent reverse engineering the sensitive data in case the data is stolen.

How should we design the system to avoid the above scenarios.

Comment: As far as the password is concerned, store it encrypted. Anyone with sufficient database privileges will be able to see data like usernames, though.

Comment: Don't store passwords [at all](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13326205/533120) (even encrypted). Just store password hashes. And [salt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_(cryptography)) them for good measure. Also see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12538258/533120).

Comment: I think this question got misunderstood, and OP means storing external logins and passwords in his db.

Answer (score 0):

You can prevent certain parameters from being shown in Rails logs with:

```
config.filter_parameters << :parameter_name
```

More information about that is available at http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#rails-general-configuration

Be aware data could still show in your database logs, or other logs your system may be collecting.

You should be encrypting things like passwords anyway, but how much access your team will have to the will presumably be affected by how much access they have to the source code/logs/database in the first place.

As for external access, a good start would be the Rails security documentation at http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html

Comment: I understand the part of not showing them in the Rails logs. How would I store user specific api_keys (say twitter, fb or flickr, youtube) in a safe manner.